# OpenCV Error: Assertion failed CvException in templmatch.cpp

Tags: android, opencv, match

Someone could explain me what does this error in logcat mean?

```
 06-19 11:52:56.198: ERROR/cv::error()(8272): OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (corrsize.height <= img.rows + templ.rows - 1 && corrsize.width <= img.cols + templ.cols - 1) in void cv::crossCorr(const cv::Mat&, const cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, cv::Size, int, cv::Point, double, int), file /home/reports/ci/slave/50-SDK/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/templmatch.cpp, line 70
 06-19 11:52:56.208: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8272): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2151
    CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: /home/reports/ci/slave/50-SDK/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/templmatch.cpp:70: error: (-215) corrsize.height <= img.rows + templ.rows - 1 && corrsize.width <= img.cols + templ.cols - 1 in function void cv::crossCorr(const cv::Mat&, const cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, cv::Size, int, cv::Point, double, int)
    ]
    at org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.matchTemplate_0(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.matchTemplate(Imgproc.java:7226)
    at com.micaela.myapp.Eye.match(Eye.java:256)
    at com.micaela.myapp.Eye.access$100(Eye.java:22)
    at com.micaela.myapp.Eye$3.run(Eye.java:146)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

This exception is called in this piece of code:

```
 Mat res;
    if ((roi.height() > MainActivity.tpl.height()) && (roi.width() > MainActivity.tpl.width())) {
        res = new Mat(new Size(roi.cols() - MainActivity.tpl.cols() + 1, roi.rows() - MainActivity.tpl.rows() + 1), CvType.CV_32FC1);
        Imgproc.matchTemplate(roi, MainActivity.tpl, res, Imgproc.TM_SQDIFF);
        if (left) {
            return new Point((eyeRect.x + this.roi.width() - matchRect.x - Math.round(Core.minMaxLoc(res).maxLoc.x + (MainActivity.tpl.width() / 2))),
                    (Math.round(Core.minMaxLoc(res).maxLoc.y + (MainActivity.tpl.height() / 2)) + matchRect.y + eyeRect.y));
        } else {
            return new Point((Math.round(Core.minMaxLoc(res).maxLoc.x + (MainActivity.tpl.width() / 2)) + matchRect.x + eyeRect.x), (Math.round(Core.minMaxLoc(res).maxLoc.y + (MainActivity.tpl.height() / 2)) + matchRect.y + eyeRect.y));
        }
    }
```

at:

```
Imgproc.matchTemplate(roi, MainActivity.tpl, res, Imgproc.TM_SQDIFF);
```

I am programming in Android, using opencv4android libraries, the last version.

Comment: is `roi` 1-channel image?

Comment: Yes, roi is 1-channel..

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your template size less than 1x1 pixel. OpenCV can't deal with empty template.

Comment: No, I have print its size in logcat, and the result is:  06-19 14:58:19.592: INFO/Tpl(8372): Tpl: 8x8

Comment: Please provide roi size too.

Comment: Its size is 06-19 18:08:50.691: INFO/Roi(4927): Roi size: 13x18.

Comment: I tested template matching with C++ on my desktop. With your sizes it worked fine. As I know OpenCV for Android uses the same C++ code, so I can only assume a stupid mistake somewhere in your code, but provided code looks normal. Good luck!

Comment: Ok, luckily now I know that the error is not in the code where I do the matching! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that all arguments to `matchTemplate()` are of correct size and type. From OpenCV documentation:

> - image – Image where the search is running. It must be 8-bit or 32-bit
>     floating-point.
> - templ – Searched template. It must be not greater than
>     the source image and have the same data type.

So make sur that `roi` is of the same type as `MainActivity.tpl` (they both must be 8-bit or 32-bit floating-point). `roi`and `MainActivity.tpl` should both have 1 channel.

Also, I don't think you have to allocate `res;` with `res = new Mat(new Size(roi.cols() - MainActivity.tpl.cols() + 1, roi.rows() - MainActivity.tpl.rows() + 1), CvType.CV_32FC1);`. I think, if it's not allocated it'll be created automatically you upon calling `matchTemplate` (although allocating `res` is recommended for speed).

Comment: You have been very clear in the explanation. Thank you! I will provide to verify that everything is okay.